# Different proofs of uniqueness of the Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

How many different types of proof do you know for the so-called Lerch's theorem, i.e., uniqueness of the Laplace transform?

I have found the following references for proofs. New books, in general, do **not** include the proof for Lerch's theorem.

- In [1, Sections 5 and 6], there is a general proof given for Stieltjes
  type Laplace transforms.
- In [2, Appendix II] and [3, Section 5], the
  proof uses substitution first and then approximation to a continuous
  functions by polynomials.
- In [4, Section 3], there is a totally
  different proof, where the author makes use of the function
  $E_{n}(\tau-t):=1-\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{e}^{nk(\tau-t)}}$ which
  converges to $H(\tau-t)$ as $n\to\infty$, where $H$ is Heaviside's
  unit function.

Do you know other proofs for Lerch's theorem.
Can you redirect me to some other proofs?

**References**

**[1]** D. V. Widder, The Laplace Transform, 
Princeton Mathematical Series, v. 6. Princeton University Press, Princeton, N. J., 1941.

**[2]** D. L. Kreider, R. G. Kuller, D. R. Ostberg, F. W. Perkins, An Introduction to Linear Analysis, Addison-Wesley Publishing Co., Inc., Reading, Mass.-Don Mills, Ont. 1966.

**[3]** G. Doetsch, Introduction to the Theory and Application of the Laplace Transformation, Springer-Verlag, New York-Heidelberg, 1974.

**[4]** E. J. Watson, Laplace Transforms and Applications, VNR New
    Mathematics Library, 10. Van Nostrand Reinhold Co., New York-London,
    1981.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this question has a well defined answer.  As far as I know, all proofs of the uniqueness of the Laplace transform are essentially corollaries of this one statement:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \text{e}^{-st} dt = 0 \implies f(t) = 0$

The number of statements equivalent to this is infinite (e.g. you could add $1$ to both sides of the equation, to get a stupid yet true statement).  Perhaps you mean to restrict the proofs to those which are reasonably simple and useful, but then we start to get into highly subjective territory.

Comment: The proof of "this one statement" is exactly what the OP is seeking. You are not adding any information. It is also not a subjective territory.